# How can I get a HTML web page from a Windows Mobile Application?

Tags: c#, html, windows-mobile

I'm working with C#.net developing applications for windows mobile 6, and i need get the HTML code from a web page, i mean, i need download the page and then get the code or parse it to string.

someone know how can i do it?

I know there is the WebClient Class for desktop app, but i didn't find something like that for mobile app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) class to make a GET request and read the HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the System.Net.WebClient class and call DownloadStringAsync to download any resource from the web asynchronously.